# When i open ubuntu terminal "~~~~" and "^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~" this characters coming non stoply . How to get ride of this?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, gnome-terminal

While using the Terminal exclusively, I frequently encounter the occurrence of ~~~~~~~~~~ and ^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~ appearing randomly. This happens even when I am not actively pressing any keys on my keyboard.

some time this "~~~~~~~" and some times this "^[[2~^[[2~^[[2~" characters are coming

[image]

I tried to reset my .bashrc file to stop this, but didn't work.

i found this : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094233/why-does-the-terminal-keep-showing-2-randomly

But not a solution to fix it.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [ubuntu.se] would be better places for questions like this.